# How to parse/check if tags (as strings) are valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, element

```
function $(selector) {

var resultObject =  {
    append: function (element) 
     {
        if(element.charAt(0) == "p")
        {
            //........

        }
    }
}
    return resultObject;
}
```

Call:

```
<p class="testing">Hallo, ich bin ein P TAG </p>
<input type="button" value="append tag/text " onclick="$('.testing').append('<ul><li>I am going to be append!</ul></li>');"
```

How can I check if the tag/s (element) is valid, so I can append it to another specified element? Is it possible to use DOM Parser? To use 1000 of if's isn't very nice...

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: Like <p>smth</p> is valid... <p>smth<  is not valid

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regex, but parsing DOM "manually" like that is **not recommended.**

Example regex (again **parsing DOM with regex should be avoided**, because it's easy to get it wrong or overlook a possible scenario)

```
/^<[^>]+>[\s\S]?<\/[^>]+>$/.test(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Every specific character is actually ANSII character which can be converted to int and vice versa for free. You can play around it and make simple hashing algorithm :) This is how I would solve this, I may be wrong.

In my opinion, if u DO need to check all elements of input, time complexity of O(n) is not so awful, so don't be mad about this.